# Liferay: Finding out the current sites' landing page url using only location.href

Tags: javascript, regex, url, liferay

I just wanted to ask if it is legitimate to use the following regex to determine a sites' landing page in Liferay using js:

```
location.href.match("^(http[s]?\:\/\/)?(.*?)\/(web|guest|group|private)\/(.*?)($|\/(.*))")
```

I would then build my URL based on what the groups return:

```
location.href.replace(/^(http[s]?\:\/\/)?(.*?)\/(web|guest|group|private)\/(.*?)($|\/(.*))/i, "$1$2/$3/$4")
```

Is this an acceptable solution or do I necessarily have to use Liferays' backend-methods to determine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be recommended to use Liferay's implicit jsp objects such  as [themedisplay](https://gist.github.com/SubhashPavuskar/6096050) to fetch required URL.It would also be safer to avoid any [paramter tampering attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering) due to malicious parameter change in URL.